# How to resolve "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The file is locked: nio:/Development/hiber/data/contactmgr.mv.db [1.4.192/7]"

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I am trying to insert mock data in H2 db using hibernate, but I am facing following error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The file is locked:
>   nio:/Development/hiber/data/contactmgr.mv.db [1.4.192/7]

, earlier I thought it was because of username and password property but I stumbled upon this error even after removing it from hibernate.cfg.xml.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:122)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
>         at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
>         at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>         at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:147)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:272)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>         at org.hibernate.metamodel.source.internal.MetadataImpl.(MetadataImpl.java:120)
>         at org.hibernate.metamodel.source.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:123)
>         at org.hibernate.metamodel.MetadataSources.buildMetadata(MetadataSources.java:151)
>         at com.hibernate.demo.Application.buildSesssionFactory(Application.java:46)
>         at com.hibernate.demo.Application.(Application.java:17)
>       Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database may be already in use: null. Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use
>   the server mode [90020-192]
>         at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
>         at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
>         at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.convertIllegalStateException(MVTableEngine.java:187)
>         at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:167)
>         at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine.init(MVTableEngine.java:99)
>         at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2463)
>         at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:692)
>         at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:270)
>         at org.h2.engine.Database.(Database.java:264)
>         at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:64)
>         at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:176)
>         at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:154)
>         at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:137)
>         at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:27)
>         at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:349)
>         at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.(JdbcConnection.java:118)
>         at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.(JdbcConnection.java:102)
>         at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
>         ... 19 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The file is locked: nio:/Development/hiber/data/contactmgr.mv.db [1.4.192/7]
>         at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:773)
>         at org.h2.mvstore.FileStore.open(FileStore.java:172)
>         at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.(MVStore.java:344)
>         at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open(MVStore.java:2893)
>         at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:154)
>         ... 34 more

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml file in use :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:./data/contactmgr</property>


        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">PUBLIC</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="com.hibernate.demo.model.Contact"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

and following is my Main class:

```
public class Application {

    //Session factory
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSesssionFactory();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Contact contact = new Contact.ContactBuilder("Bob", "marley").withEmail("marley.bob@gmail.com").withPhone(5859789791L).build();

        //Open a Session

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        //Begin a Transaction
         session.beginTransaction();


        //Use the session to save the contact

        session.save(contact);
        //Commit the transaction

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        // Close the session
        session.close();
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSesssionFactory() {
        // Create a StandardServiceRegistry
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        final ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
        return new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 7):

This exception is thrown because the H2 db file is already in use.
(Maybe because of some inconsistency or similar problems with you db file)

I suggest the following:

1. Have you tried to simply remove the file and all other intermediate files which belong to it in the folder? Afterwards just restart the app freshly with a new db file.
2. Maybe you've opened the application twice and thus causing the error? Closing all instances will get rid of the exception.

Comment: It was resolved, it was the second point in your solution that was causing it, H2 instance was running in the background and my app was trying to spun a new instance on same port, voted up. thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want any lock on your database, you can configure your database connection URL as following :

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:./data/contactmgr;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;FILE_LOCK=NO</property>
```

**Documentation :**

- http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html

Comment: Thanks! This saved my day since the database had to be opened simultaneously from 2 projects (one in read/write and the other one in read-only mode).